# Desktop app with website using data

Tags: web, desktop

I have a plan to create a desktop app (language not chosen yet) that will be used as an admin part to manipulate data. At the same time the database will be used for a website.

My only concern is -- I may mix up technologies that aren't compatible, but the only thing that ties them together is the database.

Say I will use Delphi to create the desktop app to manage an Access or MSSQL/MYSQL (if possible) and then use php as to make the web.

Can there be obvious problems with this idea that I am blind to right now?
Any other ideas suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases have to be one of the most common ways I see two languages communicating/cooperating. I've seen databases as a conduit between C/C++, Java, Perl, Python, C#, etc... Databases have the benefit of storing data in a pretty language agnostic way. Almost all languages have a way to talk to a database.

The main downside of using two different languages is that you won't be able to reuse code between your web project and your desktop project. That may sound fine, but every time you update your DB schema, you have to update the two code bases. Not a deal-breaker, but annoying nonetheless.

I would recommend avoiding Access if you could help it. Access works for a simple desktop application, but once you start introducing multiple users, you should go with something a little more robust (and secure). Go with something like SQL Server Compact or SQLite if you need a file database. I personally would bite the bullet and go right for MySQL.

Comment: Right thanks. Its annoying that's true, but this is a simple project nonetheless.